# how open in eclipse ".pro File Editor"

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, opencv

i'm need in eclipse the qt and openCV library. i'm found the tutorial  http://www.welding.iat.uni-bremen.de/cms/index.php?view=article&catid=14%3Aimage-processing&id=14%3Aa-tutorial-on-integrating-eclipse-qt-and-opencv&format=pdf&option=com_content&Itemid=24 where writen last step "
 We make sure that the Advance Mode is selected, we create a New Variable (1) and we give the name LIBS to this variable (2)
 selecting the Append as Assignment Operator.
 We have to add the following content to the variable(2),  -L/usr/local/lib -lcxcore -lcv -lhighgui -lcvaux".
how my open last window so as double clicking don't open. Opens file where code

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = ex1 
QT        += core gui 
HEADERS   += ex1.h
SOURCES   += main.cpp \
    ex1.cpp
FORMS     += ex1.ui    
RESOURCES +=
```

how my run it task?
sorry bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly:  Right click on .pro file and go to 'Qt Project Editor', if it is not there then you can use the text editor option (or something is wrong with your Eclipse Qt installation).

Comment: If you follow my instructions, the file should open where all the files do.